# How to let crawlers know about redirecting pages in Gatsby React

Tags: reactjs, seo, gatsby

I have a React component at the '/' route which checks the browser language and redirects the user to '/en' or '/es' accordingly, using Gatsby navigate method.

Now the problem is Gatsby returns a status 200 to SEO crawlers on the route '/' since it is technically not a 301 redirect, making the crawlers treat it as a separate page. Neither can I add a canonical tag to the '/' route (or meta nofollow/noindex) since it automatically picks all the metadata from the '/en' page due to the redirect.

This leads to SEO errors like duplicate meta description and title tag, missing self-reference hreflang in '/' (since it picks up the values from '/en' page).

I cannot set up a server-side 301 since I have to find the user's browser language using JavaScript code to redirect the user.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { navigate } from 'gatsby';

const LanguageSelect = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigate(`/${window.navigator.language}`);
  }, []);
  return null;
}
```

How can I let the crawlers know that the '/' route is not a standalone page and they should not consider it separate from '/en' page?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot set up a server-side 301 since I have to find the user's
> browser language using JavaScript code to redirect the user.

This leads to an impossible use-case. You can't use JavaScript (client-side) to make some calculations based on X logic (user language in this case) at the same time you try to avoid Google's crawlers indexing the site.

This kind of logic must be done in and by the server, by setting the `/` route as `/en` by default using a `301`. Once there, the user is free to change the language.